# <p> tag is a block-level element in XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

I know that in HTML4.0

```
<p>
```

tag is not a block-level element. 
What about in XHTML 1.0?

Thank you

This is the reference for HTML4.0
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

Was that my misinterpretation?

Comment: it should be noted that with css you can make something that is not a block into something that is and vice versa.

Comment: may i ask for more info on that, pleas? Thank you. I know that you cannot have an inline containing another element, which will not passed the validation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, `p` is a block-level element going back to at least HTML 3.2.

> Most elements that can appear in the
>   document body fall into one of two
>   groups: block level elements which
>   cause paragraph breaks, and text level
>   elements which don't. Common block
>   level elements include H1 to H6
>   (headers), P (paragraphs) LI (list
>   items), and HR (horizontal rules).
>   Common text level elements include EM,
>   I, B and FONT (character emphasis), A
>   (hypertext links), IMG and APPLET
>   (embedded objects) and BR (line
>   breaks). Note that block elements
>   generally act as containers for text
>   level and other block level elements
>   (excluding headings and address
>   elements), while text level elements
>   can only contain other text level
>   elements. The exact model depends on
>   the element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32

And XHTML 1.0 is really the same exact thing as HTML 4.01 except less lenient. Meaning the elements serve the same purpose, are the same "level" ( block, inline, table ), just these rules apply:

- all elements and attribute names must appear in lower case
- all attribute values must be quoted
- non-Empty Elements require a closing tag
- empty elements are terminated using a space and a trailing slash
- no attribute minimization is allowed
- in strict XHTML, all inline elements must be contained in a block element

EDIT:

> The P element represents a paragraph.
>   It cannot contain block-level elements
>   (including P itself).

This just means that the `p` cannot own other block level elements inside, meaning because it is block-level it cannot contain itself.

Comment: so is the p tag a special block-level element, since a block-level element is often the one that can contains itself, and other elements (both block-level and inline)?

Comment: Every element is unique, there are certain rules for certain elements, but yes you can consider it "special" since every element is special in its own way.

Answer (score 2):

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

This means that the P element *is* a block level element, and that it cannot contain *other* block level elements (such as DIV). Since P is itself a block level element, you cannot put a P inside another P.

Comment: so is the p tag a special block-level element, since a block-level element is often the one that can contains itself, and other elements (both block-level and inline)? thank you.