# CSS alignment: left and right issue

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm expecting to get all text aligned right, although `Support`  |  `Profile`  |  `Logout` is aligned left, while `Welcome` is aligned right. Why does it happen?

```
<div id="header">
        <a href="#">Support</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#">Profile</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#">Logout</a>
        <p>Welcome, Today is <script type="text/javascript">timeinit();</script></p>
    </div> 

   #header {
        background: #00557F;
        border-bottom: 2px gray;
        padding: 1em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
    }

    div#header p {
        color: #B7DDF2;
        font: 10px Arial;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
    }

    div#header a { 
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #B7DDF2;
        font: 10px Arial;
        text-align: right;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    } 
    div#header a:hover { 
        font: 10px Arial;
        color: #FFCF8B; 
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-align: right;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: since every child element is to be aligned right, try putting the property in the #header element and remove it from the children unless you want to override the property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#header {
    text-align:right;
}
```

add above to your div

Answer (score 2):

First of all, P is a block element, and not inline (unlike the a's),  you can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428830/1394380).

Your p element occupies 100% of the possible content width (which is all the width of the div in this case), and its text alights to the right with the css u set.

with A's its not the case; You aligned the text WITHIN the a's, and not the a's themselves.
To changed this you need to set the text-aling property for the div itself and not for the a's

Answer (score 1):

You should a a float right to your  element

`div#header a { 
 float: right;
}`