# BeautifulSoup doesn't return from h1 properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

My code

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

htmls = '''
<div class="main-content">
<h1 class="student">
    <p>Name: <br />
    Alex</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</h1>
</div>
<div class="department">
... more text
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls)
h1 = soup.find("h1", {"class": "student"})
print h1
```

Expected result

```
<h1 class="student">
    <p>Name: <br />
    Alex</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</h1>
```

But, unfortunately returns

```
<h1 class="student">
</h1>
```

My question is, why it is eating everything between the **p** tag? Does it performing **renderContents()**? Or its a failure of parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using `p` tag inside the `h1` tag. For example, if you do:

```
>>> htmls
'\n<div class="main-content">\n<h1 class="student">\n    <p>Name: <br />\n    Alex</p>\n    <p>&nbsp;</p>\n</h1>\n</div>\n<div class="department">\n... more text\n</div>\n'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls)
>>> soup

<div class="main-content">
<h1 class="student">
</h1><p>Name: <br />
    Alex</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</div>
<div class="department">
... more text
</div>
```

You can see that beautiful soup has parsed it slightly different. `p` is *after* `h1` closes.

Whereas,

```
>>> htmls = '''
... <div class="main-content">
... <h1 class="student">
...     <span>Name: <br />
...     Alex</span>
...     <span>&nbsp;</span>
... </h1>
... </div>
... <div class="department">
... ... more text
... </div>
... '''
>>> 
>>> htmls.contents
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contents'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls)
>>> h1 = soup.find("h1", {"class": "student"})
>>> 
>>> h1
<h1 class="student">
<span>Name: <br />
    Alex</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
</h1>
```

You can see the children.

This is the way HTML `p` tag behaves. Hence the issue. (Read more on [`block level elements`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428828/p-tag-is-a-block-level-element-in-xhtml) here)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a different parser into your BeautifulSoup:

```
pip install html5lib

>>> htmls = '''
... <div class="main-content">
... <h1 class="student">
...     <span>Name: <br />
...     Alex</span>
...     <span>&nbsp;</span>
... </h1>
... </div>
... <div class="department">
... ... more text
... </div>
... '''

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls, 'html5lib')
>>> h1 = soup.find('h1', 'student')
>>> print h1
<h1 class="student">
    <p>Name: <br/>
    Alex</p>
    <p> </p>
</h1>
```

Does what you want, I think. Otherwise, you shouldn't have block elements inside an  for compliance.

See: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ this for inserting a parser